# Script to find all items that do not inherit permissions

Tags: 2010, powershell

I would like a SP 2010 Powershell script which searches all folders in a library and finds the ones that do not inherit permissions from their parent.

Does anyone have one handy?  I'm new to the whole powershell/sharepoint idea, so not sure how to go about this yet.

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
asnp microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://yoururl"
$list = $web.Lists["YourLibrary"]
$list.Folders | ft Name, HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```

Comment: We used your script successfully, but instead of "Folders" used "items"
->
$list.Items | ft Name, HasUniqueRoleAssignments